# Balloon-tips with Qt

Tags: qt, balloon, balloon-tip

In my Qt application, I'd like to use balloons/balloon-tips as shown in the [Windows user experience guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742400.aspx) (not the system tray balloons).

Is this supported by Qt? I haven't found anything. Is there an Open Source library out there for this (Qxt does not have it)? What's the best way to create that myself?

Comment: To my knowledge there's nothing built into Qt that will do this. I've wanted them before and ended up writing a custom widget from scratch to do it.

Comment: Did it work satisfactorily? Would you mind sharing your solution or some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Search for `QBalloonTip` class (in Qt documentation (doxygen reference) and code base, look how it is implemented, and use similar technique.

Comment: Except that `QBalloonTip` is an internal class defined in `src/gui/utils/util/qsystemtrayicon_p.h` and not part of the public and documented API.

Comment: Qt 4.7 Assistant does not know this class. A Google search shows this an internal class used by QSystemTrayIcon and not part of the API. Are you sure this is the class I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QBalloonTip` which is an internal class defined in :

- Qt 5:

  `QtDir/Src/qtbase/src/widgets/util/qsystemtrayicon_p.h`
- Qt 4:

  `QtDir/src/gui/utils/util/qsystemtrayicon_p.h`

`QBalloonTip` inherits `QWidget` and it is implemented in `qsystemtrayicon.cpp` at the same directory. It has the following method to show a balloon tip:

```
void QBalloonTip::balloon(const QPoint& pos, int msecs, bool showArrow)
```

You can modify the source code of this class to have your desired balloon tip.

Answer (score 1):

To use private class `QBaloonTip` in Qt 5.12 you need to do the following:

1) add `QT += widgets-private` to your PRO file to be able to include private headers

2) `#include <QtWidgets/private/qsystemtrayicon_p.h>` in your source file

Then call static method `showBallon()` or instantiate it and call `baloon()`. But it is really only for system tray and it is a private API, which can change any time. I personally would not use it. But if you want to know how it is rendered, have a look at https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/util/qsystemtrayicon.cpp.html#_ZN11QBalloonTip10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent