# Where can I get the source code of class QBalloonTip

Tags: qt

I want to use the class `QBalloonTip` referred at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879205/balloon-tips-with-qt). Where can I get the source code ?

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23524411/5653461

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer but it's a step in the right direction I believe. QtBase may have the file you need. Download the source code from this location, and then search in it. I think it will get the job done. 
https://github.com/qtproject

Also, you can search from GitHub. I have searched the qt repositories with "QBalloonTip" and got this: https://github.com/search?p=1&q=org%3Aqtproject+QBalloonTip+&type=Code